# Selenium Span Scrape

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium to scrape the data within the span and my code as below, the output come out the whole span item. "280 [-49]", how to clear the remind inside span and get the value 280.

```
warrant_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="bar  tooltip_os'+str(row)+' tooltipstered"]/span').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store that value as string and later split it and take the 1st item from the list.

```
warrant_bar.split()[0]
```

you will get 280.

if this is what you are looking for then mark this answer as resolution.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, there is some entries where the inner html doesn't start with a number so this wont address every variation. I assume only looking for that number just before the square bracket.

Comment: Yes, for that only scenario he can try using a regular expression.Or else he can also count the number of items in the list after split. if the number of item is 3 then take `warrant_bar.split()[1]` or else take `warrant_bar.split()[0]`